# how to read a text file with a custom (multiline) line terminator?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge text file like this

```
1,2,3,4,5$*$*$2,5,1,3,2$*$*$
```

where `$*$*$` is the line terminator (in reality this is needed because all kind of text may be included in the regular columns: newline characters, etc).

How can I parse the `txt` file efficiently and put it into a Pandas dataframe? `pd.read_csv()` only accept length-1 line terminators... so it fails here.

Here I am looking for

```
1,2,3,4
2,5,1,3
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770985/9375102 maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can parse it before.
Though I don't know any Pandas, I managed to make it work (I think):

```
with open("your_text_file.txt") as f:
    s = f.read()
parts = s.split("$*$*$")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE'])
for i, line in enumerate(parts):
    if line:
        df.loc[i] = line.split(",")

print(df)
```

Comment: good idea, but the `txt` is written on disk. Also, I would like to put it into a pandas dataframe

Comment: of course. You have to read it first.
    with open("text_file.txt") as f:
           s = f.read().
Sadly, I am not a Pandas expert, so I can not help you in that.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing your line terminator with one that pandas can understand?

```
from io import StringIO

s = '1,2,3,4,5$*$*$2,5,1,3,2$*$*$'
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s.replace('$*$*$', '\n')), header=None)
```

will return

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  2  5  1  3  2
```

Comment: its a good idea but there could be newline characters in the regular textual variables as well...